# Joomla Module for a shopping site

Tags: module, joomla, shopping-cart

I need to know if there exists any module for joomla where every registered user is able to load articles for a shopping site, just like ebay.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "every registered user is able to load articles"?

Comment: like E-bay, when a user get signs up, he/she is able to add records to the catalog

Answer (score 0):

Mighty Resources has multi vendor support if that is what you mean.

http://www.mightyextensions.com/joomla-components/commerce-mall-b2b-b2c-c2c-private-shop